# How do i set public ip address for office?

Tags: networking, ip-address

My assignment has this thing. Im given with the public ip address of 203.220.72.0/24. This is public ip address for router.The office got 20 hots and I need to give public ip address to those hosts, not private ip address? how should i do that? Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: This is not really an appropriate place to find someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. What's preventing you from assign a public IP address to each of those hosts?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign static IP addresses to client but It's easier to use DHCP to assign dynamic address to clients.

How to configure DHCP on router depends on type of router you are using (not specified).

And never write your real IP addresses in public forums, there are some mallicious attackers just looking for this kind of things. use x.x.x.0/24 instead.

IF you need more information please ask in more detail.